# Unable to get the text with getText() in Protractor Framework

Tags: jasmine, protractor

My code looks like this

```
getTicket() {
        let box = this.waitForResponse(90);
        let deferredTicket = protractor.promise.defer();
        let me = this;

        box.getText().then(function(val) {
           let r = /.*(INC\d+) .*/;
           let ticketId = val.match(r)[1];


console.log(ticketId);
```

This was working before when we were printing the ticket number on the UI with the other text. Now ticket number is not visible on the UI but it exists in the HTML as we have just changed its color to background color. Now the framework is failing as it is unable to get ticketnumber from the UI as its invisible.What should I do? getInnerHTML() doesn't work either

Comment: try using `getAttribute("innerText")` or `getAttribute("textContent")`.

Comment: The current version of webdriver uses `getAttribute('innerHTML')` instead of getInnerHTML. You could try that.